# TYPO3: Write a ViewHelper in an extension with vendor namespace

Tags: namespaces, typo3, fluid, typo3-6.1.x

I have created an extension with plugins in a vendor namespace. Everything works fine so far. All the classes start with a namespace declaration `namespace \VENDOR\ExtensionName\...` and typo3 autoloads them just fine.

However, the problem starts when I add a ViewHelper. I put this in the `\VENDOR\ExtensionName\ViewHelpers` namespace. I added the namespace in my Fluid template like so: `{namespace ns=VENDOR\ExtensionName\ViewHelpers}`. When I call it in the template with `<ns:myViewHelper />`, I just get an 'Oops ...' error message:

```
Could not analyse class:VENDOR\ExtensionName\ViewHelpers\MyViewHelperViewHelper maybe not loaded or no autoloader?
```

The same happens, when I put the ViewHelper in a `\TYPO3\...` namespace.

How do I correctly implement a ViewHelper in an extension with a vendor namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace declaration must not have a leading backslash.

Instead having `\Vendor\ExtensionName\ViewHelpers;` it has to be `Vendor\ExtensionName\ViewHelpers;`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nested.php

Comment: If this helped you, please mark it as solved. Otherwise let me know what not worked or if you found another solution.